# Android sqlite INSERT multiple rows with same constant

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to execute the following sqlite command to copy some values in a table:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES((SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 = '2'), 1);
```

What I want is for the 1 to be used for all the `SELECT`ed rows, but it's only used once. How do I fix that?

I was thinking using a temp table with the default value to what I want. I know temp tables are used for complex queries, but it feels like this isn't *that* complicated and there could be an easier solution to this.

Example:
I want the following table...

```
column1  column2
1        2
4        2
5        3
4        4
```

...to become the following table...

```
column1  column2
1        2
4        2
5        3
4        4
1        1
4        1
```

Comment: How does your 'table' schema look?

Comment: It looks like: `CREATE TABLE 'table' ('column1' INTEGER, 'column2' INTEGER)`
(Well, slightly more complicated with `NOT NULL` etc, but that's the relevant stuff)

Comment: My question was excessive, on the second thought. The answer laalto provided is the one I had in mind. It is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to put the fixed column2 value in the select:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table (column1, column2) SELECT DISTINCT column1, 1 FROM table WHERE column2 = '2';
```

Also note the absence of `VALUES`.

Comment: Ah! So **that's** where I put the 1. Thanks a lot!